# Is there any way in php to get time zone list as like window pc?

Tags: php, timezone

Is there any way in php to get time zone list as like window pc

i want php code to get timezones in dropdown list,they are display like in this page https://code.google.com/p/cartotheque/wiki/TimeZoneList (cities have similar timezones in one option)......not in this( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_time_zones_by_country )page

Answer (score 2):

**Updated 1.0**

I already adjust the way you wanted.

Full code

```
function timezone_list() {
    static $timezones = null;

    if ($timezones === null) {
        $timezones = [];
        $offsets = [];
        $now = new DateTime();

        foreach (DateTimeZone::listIdentifiers() as $timezone) {
            $now->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone($timezone));
            $offsets[] = $offset = $now->getOffset();
            $timezones[$timezone] = '(' . format_GMT_offset($offset) . ') ' . format_timezone_name($timezone);
        }

        array_multisort($offsets, $timezones);
    }

    return $timezones;
}

function format_GMT_offset($offset) {
    $hours = intval($offset / 3600);
    $minutes = abs(intval($offset % 3600 / 60));
    return 'GMT' . ($offset ? sprintf('%+03d:%02d', $hours, $minutes) : '');
}

function format_timezone_name($name) {
    $name = str_replace('/', ', ', $name);
    $name = str_replace('_', ' ', $name);
    $name = str_replace('St ', 'St. ', $name);
    return $name;
}
```

The Output will display like this

```
Array
(
    [Pacific/Midway]    => (GMT-11:00) Pacific, Midway
    [Pacific/Niue]      => (GMT-11:00) Pacific, Niue
    [Pacific/Pago_Pago] => (GMT-11:00) Pacific, Pago Pago
    [America/Adak]      => (GMT-10:00) America, Adak
    [Pacific/Honolulu]  => (GMT-10:00) Pacific, Honolulu
    [Pacific/Johnston]  => (GMT-10:00) Pacific, Johnston
    [Pacific/Rarotonga] => (GMT-10:00) Pacific, Rarotonga
    [Pacific/Tahiti]    => (GMT-10:00) Pacific, Tahiti
    [Pacific/Marquesas] => (GMT-09:30) Pacific, Marquesas
    [America/Anchorage] => (GMT-09:00) America, Anchorage
    etc (and so on)
)
```

Comment: i want display like in this page (cities have similar timezones in one option)https://code.google.com/p/cartotheque/wiki/TimeZoneList

Comment: So? is there a problem from this coding?

Answer (score 0):

There is: [`timezone-identifiers-list`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.timezone-identifiers-list.php).

Comment: this display like                    Africa/Abidjan [1] => Africa/Accra [2] => Africa/Addis_Ababa [3] => Africa/Algiers [4] => Africa/Asmara [5] => Africa/Bamako [6] => Africa/Bangui [7] => Africa/Banjul [8] => Africa/Bissau [9] => Africa/Blantyre [10] => Africa/Brazzaville [11] => Africa/Bujumbura [12] => Africa/Cairo [13] => Africa/Casablanca [14] =>                                  i want to display like         (GMT-12:00) International Date Line West
(GMT-11:00) Midway Island, Samoa
(GMT-10:00) Hawaii
(GMT-09:00) Alaska
(GMT-08:00) Pacific Time (US & Canada)

Comment: You get an array. It is up to you to display it as you wish. Your tags do not say anything about display (HTML? PHP-GTK? WXPHP?...) so it is not included in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
You can get timezone, but as you know PHP is server side language so it will give you server timezone, so to get timezone like window pc you need to use some client side javascript, you can use jstz plug-in and you can find it here
```

http://pellepim.bitbucket.org/jstz/

Example after integration of plugin :

```
var timezone = jstz.determine();
timezone.name();
```

And it will give you answer "Asia/Kolkata"

Comment: i wnt to display timezone list just like (GMT+02:00) Helsinki, Kyiv, Riga, Sofia, Tallinn, Vilnius,(GMT+02:00) Athens, Bucharest, Istanbul,(GMT+05:30) Chennai, Kolkata, Mumbai, New Delhi..........but timezone-identifiers-list displays UTC+03:00 — Mayotte,UTC+04:00 — Réunion,UTC+05:00 — Kerguelen Islands........https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_time_zones_by_country

Comment: You can use jstz for the same OR you can use moment js plugin for format. you can get it here : http://momentjs.com/

Answer (score 0):

Use can get timezone Listing using something like this:

```
<?php
    $timezones = DateTimeZone::listIdentifiers(DateTimeZone::ALL);
    echo '<pre>';
        print_r($timezones );
    echo '</pre>';
?>
```

Comment: OP want to get list of time zone.